# Android split view into vertices and transform

Tags: android, view, transform

Is it possible to take a view in Android (lets say an ImageView) and split it vertically in the middle, then fold the view in on itself in 3d?
Thus recreating something like this:
[image]

In the end I am aiming to recreate a folding effect for the sliding menu by jeremy feinstein.

I searched the web, but it didn't yield any useful results, mainly because I am unsure what exactly to search for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this liberary it will help you to achieve your goal https://github.com/tibi1712/Folding-Android

Comment: happy to help you please accept my answer if you find relevant.